# Adding N characters to a string

Tags: c#, strings

I need to prepend N spaces to a string to make it 10 characters in length. I came up with the following method, but since it is going to be called often, I want to ensure it is optimized. Could this be made more efficient?

```
public static string PrependSpaces(string str)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(str);
    for (int i = 0; i < (10 - str.Length); i++)
    {
        sb.Insert(0, " ");
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you need to prepend a number of characters to a string you might consider [String.PadLeft()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padleft(v=vs.110).aspx).

For example:

```
string str = "abc123";
Console.WriteLine(str);
str = str.PadLeft(10);
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Will produce:

```
abc123
    abc123
```

On the efficiency of your example, `StringBuilder.Append()` is more efficient than `StringBuilder.Insert()`, so you might try something like:

```
public static string PrependSpaces2(string str)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < (10 - str.Length); i++)
    {
        sb.Append(" ");
    }
    sb.Append(str);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

**EDIT** As svick suggested, [Append(char, repeat)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxyxbz2e(v=vs.110).aspx) is simpler and faster on the order of the native Pad methods:

```
public static string PrependSpaces3(string str)
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if((NUM - str.Length) > 0)
    {
        sb.Append(' ', (NUM - str.Length));
    }
    sb.Append(str);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Which when tested with this:

```
string str = "abc123";
Console.WriteLine("str: " + str);

int iterations = 100000;

string result = string.Empty;
Stopwatch s1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
{
    result = PrependSpaces(str);
}
s1.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(iterations + " calls to PrependSpaces took: {0:0.00 ms}", s1.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);

string result2 = string.Empty;
Stopwatch s2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
{
    result2 = PrependSpaces2(str);
}
s2.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(iterations + " calls to PrependSpaces2 took: {0:0.00 ms}", s2.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);

string result3 = string.Empty;
Stopwatch s3 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
{
    result3 = str.PadLeft(NUM, ' ');
}
s3.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(iterations + " calls to String.PadLeft(" + NUM + ", ' ') took: {0:0.00 ms}", s3.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);

string result4 = string.Empty;
Stopwatch s4 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
{
    result4 = PrependSpaces3(str);
}
s4.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(iterations + " calls to PrependSpaces3 took: {0:0.00 ms}", s3.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
```

returns this (benchmarks for prepending 1000 characters):

```
str: abc123
100000 calls to PrependSpaces took: 20190.16 ms
100000 calls to PrependSpaces2 took: 1025.87 ms
100000 calls to String.PadLeft(1000, ' ') took: 84.32 ms
100000 calls to PrependSpaces3 took: 84.32 ms
```

for prepending 10 characters:

```
100000 calls to PrependSpaces took: 31.02 ms
100000 calls to PrependSpaces2 took: 11.41 ms
100000 calls to String.PadLeft(10, ' ') took: 4.53 ms
100000 calls to PrependSpaces3 took: 4.53 ms
```

Comment: Instead of the `Append()` loop, you can use `sb.Append(' ', 10 - str.Length)`.